# gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory #include "gtest/gtest.h"

Tags: unit-testing, testing, makefile, cmake, googletest

I have never encountered a problem with testing my code using gtest a few months ago until recently I encountered a problem where all of a sudden the `"gtest/gtest.h"` header file can no longer be found. I am using putty to hold all my files and directories and the googletest directory is located in the same filepath as the unit test I am compiling to generate the executable. The gtest GitHub was recently updated so I'm not sure if that might have caused it. I have used `git submodule add <gtest URL>` and the it says that googletest already exists. I have always built my files using `cmake3 .`, but now I keep getting errors regarding the `TEST()` functions within the unit test file. I assume this is because the gtest directory cannot be found. I also tried using `cmake .` to build but that results in a ton of untrackable errors with the gtest.h header file itself. Apparently it seems that building with `cmake .` can track the gtest.h header file while building with `cmake3 .` cannot. I still have no clue on how to solve this error.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(googletest)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test
       unit_test.cpp
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test gtest)
TARGET_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS(test PRIVATE gtest_disable_pthreads=ON)
```

EDIT:: I forgot to include that the initial error in the title post occurs after compiling the unit test file separate to using `cmake` or `make`. I use the following command `g++ -std=c++11 unit_test.cpp` in order to compile and the resulting error is `gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory #include "gtest/gtest.h"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of *describing* the error and *guessing* what it could mean, just **show** that error (add it to the question post).

Comment: I am getting a long chain of errors when using makefile, but many of them include errors regarding expectations of a class declaration before using the ```TEST()``` function which more than likely defined within the ```gtest/gtest.h``` header file. the question title is the errors itself.

Comment: "I use the following command `g++ -std=c++11 unit_test.cpp`" - This definitely won't work, as doesn't contain `-I` option with include directory of the googletest. But you have `CMakeLists.txt`, why do not use `cmake` and `make`? I don't understand what do you want from us...

Comment: I am not sure about your last idea there but I have already explained that I already use cmake to build all my files. The issue is that all the many errors that are generated from using ```make``` are caused by functions dependent on the ```gtest/gtest.h``` header file. I have compiled test files in the past using that command line without including the directory of the googletest without a problem. If I have to include the directory then how should I format the command line?

Comment: Please, choose and state the way how do you want to build your executable. If you **want** to use `cmake` + `make`, then do not show the errors emitted by pure command line but show the errors emitted by `make`. If you **want** to use **command line**, then why do you show `CMakeLists.txt`? "I have compiled test files in the past using that command line without including the directory of the googletest without a problem." - Possibly that time you had googletest to be installed system-wide.